# Front-End disappears while creating a drop-down list in php populated by oracle database

Tags: php, oracle, dropdown

I am working on a CRUD web application. Using php and oracle database. I want to make a dropdown populated by the data in the database.
Here's the code.

queries.php

```
public static function getAllNames(string $mmid){
        $dbUser = "...";
        $dbPass = "...";
        $dbConn = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=...)(PORT=...))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=...)))"; 
        $conn = oci_connect($dbUser, $dbPass, $dbConn);
        $sql = oci_parse($conn,"SELECT * FROM mmPERSON where mmid = :mmid");
        oci_bind_by_name($sql, ':mmId', $mmId);
        oci_execute($sql, OCI_DEFAULT);
        oci_fetch_all($sql);
       $results = oci_result($sql, 'FNAME');
        return $results;
    }
```

roles.php

```
<?php
$mmid = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "fname");
require_once './pages/header.php';
require_once './functions/queries.php';
$nameArr = Queries::getAllNames($mmid);
?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
    <div id="addroles" class="hide" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <div id="resultActivityContent"></div>
    </div>  
    <form class="cmxform" id="addroles">
        <legend>Add Roles</legend>
        <label for="names">Select Name</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="names" id="names">
           <option selected disabled></option>
           <?php
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($nameArr); $i++) {
                echo '<option value="' . $nameArr[$i][''] . '">' . $nameArr[$i][''] . '</option>';
            }
           ?>
        </select>     
        <br>
        <br>

    </form>
            </div>
     </div>       
</div>
```

When I delete that line of code($nameArr = Queries::getAllNames($mmid);) from roles.php the frontend is visible else the page is blank. There is something wrong with that line of code. I've been trying to find out since past two days.

I am new to php. Please review the code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);  // In PHP 5.3 use E_ALL|E_STRICT
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` to your code and check what errors are being produced

Comment: Getting this error:
"Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on resource in /home/queries.php:13\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/roles.php(5): Queries::getAllNames('MMID')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /home/queries.php on line 13"

Comment: I don't see you calling `prepare()` on any of your objects in `queries.php`. Is the actual code different then what you shared here? The error suggests you are trying to call a function called `prepare()` in `queries.php` which doesn't exist.

Comment: Hey, this is the actual code. Why would anyone post a different code here lol. 
The code is exactly the same.